# How to check whether Excel file is password protected?

Tags: excel, vba, passwords

Is there a way to check whether an Excel file is password protected (Password to open) other than trying to open the file, on the **VBA level**?

I am using below code in a loop which tries to open the file with password provided.

I would like to skip not protected files up front.

```
Set Workbook = appExcelPass.Workbooks.Open(strPath, False, True, Password:=arrPassword(j))
```